# MYSQL table with JSON only returns first record

Tags: php, mysql, json, slim

I have a MYSQL table with an "items" column which I am storing a JSON object. For some strange reason, only the first record is returned. For example: I am fetching based on "owner_id", and no matter what the owner_id is for the first record (1, 6, 9, 263....whatever) it always only returns the first record. BUT if this owner_id has other "items" in this table, they are also returned. Strange.

Table example:

```
id:  |  owner_id:  |  items:
----------------------------------
1    |  1          |  {
                         "items": [{
                            "q": "1",
                            "d": "I'd rather be a bird than a fish.",
                            "u": "637.30"
                         },
                         {
                            "q": "6",
                            "d": "Christmas is coming.",
                            "u": "844.57"
                          }
                         ]
                       }
----------------------------------
2    |  11         |   {
                         "items": [{
                            "q": "4",
                            "d": "I often see the time 12:34.",
                            "u": "85.85"
                         },
                         {
                            "q": "6",
                            "d": "Wow, does that work?",
                            "u": "286.27"
                          }
                         ]
                       }
```

IF I delete the items column, then I can retrieve any record request with no issues.

Should be noted I am using Slim to make the db requests. 
Here is the code for the request/query:

```
$app->get('/api/items/{id}', function(Request $request, Response $response){
   $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE owner_id = $id";

   try{

      $db = new db();
      $db = $db->connect();

      $stmt = $db->query($sql);
      $invoices = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      $db = NULL;

      echo json_encode($invoices);

   } catch(PDOException $e){

      echo '{"error": {"text": ' . $e->getMessage() . '} }';

   }
});
```

Any idea what is happening, and why I cannot get the other records in the table?

Thank you,

-S

Comment: Is this a typo, or is your database column really called owner_Id with a capital I while your sql query specifies owner_id with a lower case i?

Comment: FYI: You are vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @miknik typo... should be owner_id.

Comment: @Ivar Yes, I am aware of this. Thanks for the concern.

Comment: For testing, did you try to omit `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` from the `fetchAll` and see what it returns?

Comment: Also, if you are only selecting one row (owner_id is unique, right?) then you could just use `$stmt->->fetch();` instead... but I don't believe thats where the problem is happening. Kind of odd what you describe, given the code provided :/

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` isn't a valid argument to `fetchAll()`

Comment: @Randall I tried your suggestions and still happening. It is really strange. If I delete the "items" column the app then starts working fine. weird.

Comment: That is what is so boggling about it! There must be some other code you have (not shown?) which is causing some odd conflict of interest in the db interaction, or something. Have you tried to forgo using Slim, and just hand write out a db connection doing the same thing?

Comment: @Randall I have not yet. Lol, if I just use $stmt->fetch() it retrieves the records for owner_id 1 and owner_id 2, trying any other owner_id renders nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above wont work because you are requesting a single mysql column and the json id have nothing to do with mysql.

I modified it to suite your needs

```
$db = new db();
$db = $db->connect();

$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$invoices = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$db = NULL;

// to get individual json
// loop through 
// assuming you want the first data 
$arr = json_decode($invoices[0]->items);



// all single data
echo json_encode($arr);

// or get single
$id = 6; // can be added dynamically

$json = '';
foreach($arr as $i => $val){
    if($val['items']['q'] === $id){
        $json =  json_encode($val);
    }
}

// individual json
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your suggestion. If i type anything else in the "items" rows such as Lorem, it then retrieves the data for me with no issues. Same deal if I delete the "items" column. Why is it behaving this way when the rows are filled with the JSON objects? I don't need to render the output in the php file...I am retrieving the data from another app, but making the requests with POSTMAN or something similar only works for the first record and all matching owner_ids

Comment: If i understand you correctly ` $invoices` is the variable from the database results, which have all the code record in that `sql` table.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It holds the data that was fetched using the {id}, which is the owner_id, for that particular owner. Meaning owner_id #1 could have 10 rows of data, and they retrieve fine, But owner_id #2 has 3 rows of data and nothing gets retrieved when the '/api/items/2' is ran.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your time and efforts. In the end, it was a stupid mistake on my part... I had some special html characters for the ellipsis and apostrophes in the "items" fields, which was causing some sort of glitch.